# ckeditor как сделать поле в админке не обязательным?

Tags: python, django, ckeditor

Проект на Django. Модель содержит текстовое поле с параметром blank=True.
Решил добавить ckeditor для добавления в данное поле фотографии с компьютера.
Все работает, но текстовое поле стало обязательным. Как решить эту проблему.

Код:

admin.py

```
class FamilyAdminForm(forms.ModelForm):
    descriptions = RichTextField("Описание", blank=True, null=True)
```

models.py

```
class Family(models.Model):
    descriptions = models.CharField("Описание", blank=True, null=True)
```